# Editing texture image not working

Tags: image, texture-painting

The texture image is a .dds file. I put it on the object in the material property. Is there a way I can edit this image in Blender? I go to *texture painting* and I can paint something on the image but Blender does not save it.

Answer (score 1):

Since .dds isn't a supported format in Blender, you may find it necessary to convert the dds to tiff and then back again after your texture work is complete.

Comment: can I convert dds to tiff and then import the tiff to material in blender?

Comment: .dds is an image format for DirectX according to what I am reading online, so the material you set up would have to use existing UVs for mapping the image texture and yes, the tiff image could work as your image texture in Blender. Try on a small scale test first so you don't run into issues with your project while testing.